# Webpack 4, this.htmlWebpackPlugin.getHooks is not a function

Tags: webpack

I'm migrating from webpack 3 to 4 and it is painfull ;)

I'm getting this error:

```
this.htmlWebpackPlugin.getHooks is not a function
```

I was trying to upgrade all plugins but maybe I'm missing something here?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There was [an update](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/issues/1068#issuecomment-454840740) to the thread that Bruce linked. As explained by **adambreznicky** to fix the issue one should:

1. delete old node_modules and reinstall fresh
2. `npm i --save-dev html-webpack-plugin@next`
3. modify `new InterpolateHtmlPlugin(env.raw)` to `new InterpolateHtmlPlugin(HtmlWebpackPlugin, env.raw)`

Comment: No matching version found for html-webpack-plugin@next.

Answer (score 0):

Does the advice at https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/issues/1068 fix your issue?

Comment: It didn't work for me at all, I'm getting the same error all the time, allthough I updated everything as described. Anyone fixed this ?