# Plugin could not be registered at 'html-webpack-plugin-before-html-processing'. Hook was not found

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, create-react-app, webpack-dev-server

```
this is the error: Plugin could not be registered at 'html-webpack-plugin-before-html-processing'. Hook was not found.
BREAKING CHANGE: There need to exist a hook at 'this.hooks'. To create a compatibility layer for this hook, hook into 'this._pluginCompat'.

here is the code of  package.json file of my react project
    
    {
      "name": "burger-project",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "autoprefixer": "7.1.6",
        "axios": "^0.19.2",
        "babel-core": "6.26.0",
        "babel-eslint": "7.2.3",
        "babel-jest": "^26.3.0",
        "babel-loader": "7.1.2",
        "babel-preset-react-app": "^3.1.2",
        "babel-runtime": "6.26.0",
        "case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "2.1.1",
        "chalk": "1.1.3",
        "dotenv": "4.0.0",
        "dotenv-expand": "4.2.0",
        "eslint": "4.10.0",
        "eslint-config-react-app": "^2.1.0",
        "eslint-loader": "1.9.0",
        "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "2.39.1",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "2.8.0",
        "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "5.1.1",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "7.4.0",
        "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "3.0.2",
        "file-loader": "1.1.5",
        "fs-extra": "3.0.1",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "2.29.0",
        "jest": "^26.4.2",
        "object-assign": "4.1.1",
        "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "3.2.0",
        "postcss-loader": "2.0.8",
        "promise": "8.0.1",
        "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
        "raf": "3.4.0",
        "react": "^16.8.0",
        "react-dev-utils": "^5.0.2",
        "react-dom": "^16.8.0",
        "react-redux": "^7.2.1",
        "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
        "redux": "^4.0.5",
        "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
        "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
        "resolve": "1.6.0",
        "style-loader": "0.19.0",
        "sw-precache-webpack-plugin": "0.11.4",
        "url-loader": "0.6.2",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^2.7.1",
        "webpack-manifest-plugin": "1.3.2",
        "whatwg-fetch": "2.0.3"
      },
      "scripts": {
        "start": "node scripts/start.js",
        "build": "node scripts/build.js",
        "test": "node scripts/test.js --env=jsdom"
      },
      "jest": {
        "collectCoverageFrom": \[
          "src/**/*.{js,jsx,mjs}"
        \],
        "setupFiles": \[
          "<rootDir>/config/polyfills.js"
        \],
        "testMatch": \[
          "<rootDir>/src/**/__tests__/**/*.{js,jsx,mjs}",
          "<rootDir>/src/**/?(*.)(spec|test).{js,jsx,mjs}"
        \],
        "testEnvironment": "node",
        "testURL": "http://localhost",
        "transform": {
          "^.+\\.(js|jsx|mjs)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
          "^.+\\.css$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/cssTransform.js",
          "^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|mjs|css|json)$)": "<rootDir>/config/jest/fileTransform.js"
        },
        "transformIgnorePatterns": \[
          "\[/\\\\\]node_modules\[/\\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx|mjs)$"
        \],
        "moduleNameMapper": {
          "^react-native$": "react-native-web"
        },
        "moduleFileExtensions": \[
          "web.js",
          "js",
          "json",
          "web.jsx",
          "jsx",
          "node",
          "mjs"
        \]
      },
      "babel": {
        "presets": \[
          "react-app"
        \]
      },
      "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": "react-app"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "babel-plugin-add-module-exports": "^1.0.2",
        "css-loader": "^4.2.1",
        "preload-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0-beta.3",
        "webpack": "^4.44.1"
      }
    }
```

Plugin could not be registered at 'html-webpack-plugin-before-html-processing'. Hook was not found.
BREAKING CHANGE: There need to exist a hook at 'this.hooks'. To create a compatibility layer for this hook, hook into 'this._pluginCompat'.

here is the webpack.config.dev.js file from my create-react-app:

```
//'use strict';
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CaseSensitivePathsPlugin = require('case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin');
const InterpolateHtmlPlugin = require('react-dev-utils/InterpolateHtmlPlugin');
const WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin = require('react-dev-utils/WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin');
const eslintFormatter = require('react-dev-utils/eslintFormatter');
const ModuleScopePlugin = require('react-dev-utils/ModuleScopePlugin');
const getClientEnvironment = require('./env');
const paths = require('./paths');

// Webpack uses `publicPath` to determine where the app is being served from.
// In development, we always serve from the root. This makes config easier.
const publicPath = '/';
// `publicUrl` is just like `publicPath`, but we will provide it to our app
// as %PUBLIC_URL% in `index.html` and `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` in JavaScript.
// Omit trailing slash as %PUBLIC_PATH%/xyz looks better than %PUBLIC_PATH%xyz.
const publicUrl = '';
// Get environment variables to inject into our app.
const env = getClientEnvironment(publicUrl);

// This is the development configuration.
// It is focused on developer experience and fast rebuilds.
// The production configuration is different and lives in a separate file.
module.exports = {
  // You may want 'eval' instead if you prefer to see the compiled output in DevTools.
  // See the discussion in https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/343.
  devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
  // These are the "entry points" to our application.
  // This means they will be the "root" imports that are included in JS bundle.
  // The first two entry points enable "hot" CSS and auto-refreshes for JS.
  entry: [
    // We ship a few polyfills by default:
    require.resolve('./polyfills'),
    // Include an alternative client for WebpackDevServer. A client's job is to
    // connect to WebpackDevServer by a socket and get notified about changes.
    // When you save a file, the client will either apply hot updates (in case
    // of CSS changes), or refresh the page (in case of JS changes). When you
    // make a syntax error, this client will display a syntax error overlay.
    // Note: instead of the default WebpackDevServer client, we use a custom one
    // to bring better experience for Create React App users. You can replace
    // the line below with these two lines if you prefer the stock client:
    // require.resolve('webpack-dev-server/client') + '?/',
    // require.resolve('webpack/hot/dev-server'),
    require.resolve('react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient'),
    // Finally, this is your app's code:
    paths.appIndexJs,
    // We include the app code last so that if there is a runtime error during
    // initialization, it doesn't blow up the WebpackDevServer client, and
    // changing JS code would still trigger a refresh.
  ],
  output: {
    // Add /* filename */ comments to generated require()s in the output.
    pathinfo: true,
    // This does not produce a real file. It's just the virtual path that is
    // served by WebpackDevServer in development. This is the JS bundle
    // containing code from all our entry points, and the Webpack runtime.
    filename: 'static/js/bundle.js',
    // There are also additional JS chunk files if you use code splitting.
    chunkFilename: 'static/js/[name].chunk.js',
    // This is the URL that app is served from. We use "/" in development.
    publicPath: publicPath,
    // Point sourcemap entries to original disk location (format as URL on Windows)
    devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: info =>
      path.resolve(info.absoluteResourcePath).replace(/\\/g, '/'),
  },
  resolve: {
    // This allows you to set a fallback for where Webpack should look for modules.
    // We placed these paths second because we want `node_modules` to "win"
    // if there are any conflicts. This matches Node resolution mechanism.
    // https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/253
    modules: ['node_modules', paths.appNodeModules].concat(
      // It is guaranteed to exist because we tweak it in `env.js`
      process.env.NODE_PATH.split(path.delimiter).filter(Boolean)
    ),
    // These are the reasonable defaults supported by the Node ecosystem.
    // We also include JSX as a common component filename extension to support
    // some tools, although we do not recommend using it, see:
    // https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/290
    // `web` extension prefixes have been added for better support
    // for React Native Web.
    extensions: ['.web.js', '.mjs', '.js', '.json', '.web.jsx', '.jsx'],
    alias: {
      
      // Support React Native Web
      // https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/08/a-glimpse-into-the-future-with-react-native-for-web/
      'react-native': 'react-native-web',
    },
    plugins: [
      // Prevents users from importing files from outside of src/ (or node_modules/).
      // This often causes confusion because we only process files within src/ with babel.
      // To fix this, we prevent you from importing files out of src/ -- if you'd like to,
      // please link the files into your node_modules/ and let module-resolution kick in.
      // Make sure your source files are compiled, as they will not be processed in any way.
      new ModuleScopePlugin(paths.appSrc, [paths.appPackageJson]),
    ],
  },
  module: {
    strictExportPresence: true,
    rules: [
      // TODO: Disable require.ensure as it's not a standard language feature.
      // We are waiting for https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2176.
      // { parser: { requireEnsure: false } },

      // First, run the linter.
      // It's important to do this before Babel processes the JS.
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx|mjs)$/,
        enforce: 'pre',
        use: [
          {
            options: {
              formatter: eslintFormatter,
              eslintPath: require.resolve('eslint'),
              
            },
            loader: require.resolve('eslint-loader'),
          },
        ],
        include: paths.appSrc,
      },
      {
        // "oneOf" will traverse all following loaders until one will
        // match the requirements. When no loader matches it will fall
        // back to the "file" loader at the end of the loader list.
        oneOf: [
          // "url" loader works like "file" loader except that it embeds assets
          // smaller than specified limit in bytes as data URLs to avoid requests.
          // A missing `test` is equivalent to a match.
          {
            test: [/\.bmp$/, /\.gif$/, /\.jpe?g$/, /\.png$/],
            loader: require.resolve('url-loader'),
            options: {
              limit: 10000,
              name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
            },
          },
          // Process JS with Babel.
          {
            test: /\.(js|jsx|mjs)$/,
            include: paths.appSrc,
            loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
            options: {
              
              // This is a feature of `babel-loader` for webpack (not Babel itself).
              // It enables caching results in ./node_modules/.cache/babel-loader/
              // directory for faster rebuilds.
              cacheDirectory: true,
            },
          },
          // "postcss" loader applies autoprefixer to our CSS.
          // "css" loader resolves paths in CSS and adds assets as dependencies.
          // "style" loader turns CSS into JS modules that inject <style> tags.
          // In production, we use a plugin to extract that CSS to a file, but
          // in development "style" loader enables hot editing of CSS.
          {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: [
              require.resolve('style-loader'),
              {
                loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
                options: {
                  importLoaders: 1,
                  modules: true,
                  localIdentName: '[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]'
                },
              },
              {
                loader: require.resolve('postcss-loader'),
                options: {
                  // Necessary for external CSS imports to work
                  // https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2677
                  ident: 'postcss',
                  plugins: () => [
                    require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes'),
                    autoprefixer({
                      browsers: [
                        '>1%',
                        'last 4 versions',
                        'Firefox ESR',
                        'not ie < 9', // React doesn't support IE8 anyway
                      ],
                      flexbox: 'no-2009',
                    }),
                  ],
                },
              },
            ],
          },
          // "file" loader makes sure those assets get served by WebpackDevServer.
          // When you `import` an asset, you get its (virtual) filename.
          // In production, they would get copied to the `build` folder.
          // This loader doesn't use a "test" so it will catch all modules
          // that fall through the other loaders.
          {
            // Exclude `js` files to keep "css" loader working as it injects
            // its runtime that would otherwise processed through "file" loader.
            // Also exclude `html` and `json` extensions so they get processed
            // by webpacks internal loaders.
            exclude: [/\.(js|jsx|mjs)$/, /\.html$/, /\.json$/],
            loader: require.resolve('file-loader'),
            options: {
              name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      // ** STOP ** Are you adding a new loader?
      // Make sure to add the new loader(s) before the "file" loader.
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    // Makes some environment variables available in index.html.
    // The public URL is available as %PUBLIC_URL% in index.html, e.g.:
    // <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
    // In development, this will be an empty string.
    new InterpolateHtmlPlugin(env.raw),
    // Generates an `index.html` file with the <script> injected.
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      inject: true,
      template: paths.appHtml,
    }),
    // Add module names to factory functions so they appear in browser profiler.
    new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
    // Makes some environment variables available to the JS code, for example:
    // if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') { ... }. See `./env.js`.
    new webpack.DefinePlugin(env.stringified),
    // This is necessary to emit hot updates (currently CSS only): 
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    // Watcher doesn't work well if you mistype casing in a path so we use
    // a plugin that prints an error when you attempt to do this.
    // See https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/240
    new CaseSensitivePathsPlugin(),
    // If you require a missing module and then `npm install` it, you still have
    // to restart the development server for Webpack to discover it. This plugin
    // makes the discovery automatic so you don't have to restart.
    // See https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/186
    new WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin(paths.appNodeModules),
    // Moment.js is an extremely popular library that bundles large locale files
    // by default due to how Webpack interprets its code. This is a practical
    // solution that requires the user to opt into importing specific locales.
    // https://github.com/jmblog/how-to-optimize-momentjs-with-webpack
    // You can remove this if you don't use Moment.js:
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/),
  ],
  // Some libraries import Node modules but don't use them in the browser.
  // Tell Webpack to provide empty mocks for them so importing them works.
  node: {
    dgram: 'empty',
    fs: 'empty',
    net: 'empty',
    tls: 'empty',
    child_process: 'empty',
  },
  // Turn off performance hints during development because we don't do any
  // splitting or minification in interest of speed. These warnings become
  // cumbersome.
  performance: {
    hints: false,
  },
};
```

Comment: This is likely an issue with your webpack config. Can we see your webpack.config.js file?

Comment: Yes, I'm pitching it here

Answer (score 0):

From [this post](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/issues/875#issuecomment-385140346), it looks like you need to switch the order of InterpolateHtmlPlugin(env.raw) and HtmlWebpackPlugin().

Comment: that answer was for yarn build and I didn't get that error upon yarn build so..

Comment: You should answer your own post then and mark it as the solution for future users with this issue!

Comment: I haven't yet got the solution to my issue. still struggling with it!

Comment: @codelover I'm facing the same issue. any update on your end?

Comment: @SteveTolba, I tried quite a few ways and then I couldn't find a solution so I left it since a long time. Do share if you find anything that works!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. I got it fixed after updating `react-dev-utils` package to version 7 and then following the advice from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58466751/5460023) which is replacing `new InterpolateHtmlPlugin(env.raw)` with `new InterpolateHtmlPlugin(HtmlWebpackPlugin, env.raw)`.